# IE 8 Canvas using excanvas polyfill: no errors, but animation is not running on IE 8

Tags: canvas, internet-explorer-8, html5-canvas, polyfills

I have an animation using canvas that is working fine in Chrome. I am using the excanvas polyfill for IE 8 support. I attached excanvas using an IE conditional tag in the head, as per the [excanvas instructions](https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions).

[Working page here](http://mike-eng.com/sandbox/xmas-ecard/) | [Full code on Github](https://github.com/mrengy/xmas-ecard)

The simplified HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--[if gte IE 9]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /><![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ecard.css">

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/vendor/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="card" width="1000" height="750"></canvas>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <script src="js/ecard.js"></script>
</body>
```

I am defining ctx using a ternary operator as recommended by the answer

```
var canvas = (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) != 'undefined') ? G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement($("canvas#card")[0]) : $("canvas#card")[0];
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

When I try to run the animation from IE 8, it does nothing. I see no errors in IE 8 Developer Tools. However, when I type `ctx.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100);` in the IE 8 Developer Tools console and run it, I get the error " 'ctx' is undefined".

From IE 8 developer tools, it seems that excanvas.js is loaded properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try by adding this to the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

In standard mode VML used by excanvas is turned off.

And instead of this (if still a problem):

```
ctx = $("canvas#card")[0].getContext('2d');
```

try with:

```
var canvas = (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) != 'undefined') ? G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement($("canvas#card")[0]) : $("canvas#card")[0];

ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Comment: This https://github.com/mrengy/xmas-ecard/commit/f38c8a634b3dda86bfebc6596c98783dd605be82 got rid of the error "Object doesn't support this property or method", however when I type `ctx.fillRect(25,25,100,100);` into the console in IE 8 developer tools and click "Run Script" , I get an error " 'ctx' is undefined "

Comment: @MikeEng the last is because ctx is defined in the scope of the anonymous function called when document is loaded. If you move `var ctx;` to the global scope you should be able to use it from console. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but actually ctx is declared in the global scope already. I didn't include that part of the code in the question, but see github.com/mrengy/xmas-ecard/blob/master/js/ecard.js