# Three js Browser Compatibility

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, webgl

How to activate `webgl` in internet explorer 8 version. Firefox and chrome working fine for me. Kindly help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Three.js browser compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850210/three-js-browser-compatibility)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 does not support either WebGL nor HTML5 Canvas, so this can't be done. There is a canvas [polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684251/ie-8-canvas-using-excanvas-polyfill-no-errors-but-animation-is-not-running-on) for older IE, but this will most likely not work with three.js.

Possible alternatives is to look for Flash or Java based solution, even technology such as [VRML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRML). However, none of these will be compatible with three.js code so a rewrite/adaptation from what you have in three.js will be required.

My recommendation would be to not support IE8 at all.